# Why can't you shift+click to expand selection inside of anchor tag in contentEditable?

Tags: html, hyperlink, contenteditable, text-editor, rich-text-editor

I noticed that you can't shift+click to select text within an anchor tag in `contentEditable` across browsers and editor projects, but I'm not sure why this behavior occurs.

---

[**For example:**](https://codepen.io/joen/pen/KKgOrGK)

```html
<p>
    <a href="https://google.com" contenteditable>Link to Google</a>
</p>
```

---

This also affects ProseMirror, CKEditor, and others and it occurs in every browser I've tested.

Is this behavior defined in a specification somewhere? Is there any way to override it?

What I'm looking to do is select like below. It can be done with `Shift+ArrowKeys` but not with `Shift+Click`. Why?

[image]

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.